# How do I use multiple wildcard reg expressions in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

**Problem:** I am attempting to use wildcard regular expressions in notepad++ however it is not working. I have made sure the search mode has regular expression checked.

**My code:**

```
<!--.*--><script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/example.php?id=.*"></script><!--/.*-->
```

**Original line:**

```
<!--093845--><script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/example.php?id=847584"></script><!--/023456-->
```

**Question:** What am I doing wrong with my code, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `.*` is greedy. Use lazy: `.*?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should match what you're looking for (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/oF6xF1)):

```
<!--\d+--><script type="text/javascript" src="http://example\.com/example\.php\?id=\d+"></script><!--/\d+-->
```

Note that in the demo, the slashes have to be escaped, but you don't need to do that in N++, the regex above will work (if I have understood your requirements).

Comment: How is it different from @RolandKrüger 's answer?

Comment: @M42 I didn't want to criticize Roland's answer, but since you ask... It has several problems. First, it doesn't work: see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/pQ1lB2). The reason it doesn't work is that he doesn't escape special regex characters, such as the `?` in the GET string, which makes the final `p` in `php` optional, but does not match the `?` that we actually want to match. With regex, as I'm sure you know, something a bit different may look pedantic but it can be the difference between success and failure... the devil is in the details. :)

Comment: +1 - Sorry, I didn't see the escaped char. You're perfectly right. I had to read more carefuly.

Comment: @M42 no worries. I hesitated before posting such a close answer, but then thought that a working answer is quite a bit different. :)

Comment: @zx81 +1 for your comment. You're absolutely correct. I redacted my answer accordingly.

Comment: @RolandKrüger Hey no worries, I forget simple stuff all the time. :) Sorry about all the attention.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to achieve, it would be nice if you explained what you intend to do. But I see one problem in your regular expression: The regex `.*` is too generic. The first `.*` would match right to the end of the line.

I presume what you need is something like that, as you seem to only want to match numbers:

```
<!--\d+--><script type="text/javascript" src="http://example\.com/example\.php\?id=\d+"></script><!--/\d+-->
```

**Edit:** Escaped special characters `.` and `?` to make the regex work. Credits go to [zx81](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1078583/zx81) for the correct solution.